# Get category name from param ID?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table called `:categories`, on which there is a `:name` column.

**I have an action in my controller to fetch the category of a product and filter by category:**

```
  def from_category
    @products = Product.where(category_id: params[:cat_id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

**Once I've filtered, I show the filtered products in a partial:**

```
<%= render partial: 'products', locals: { products: @products} %>
```

**from_category.js**

```
$("#products").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'products', locals: { products: @products } ) %>");
```

**Can I access the name of the category in this javascript file by only having the category ID in the params?**

**I have an url like:**

```
localhost:4000/fetch_products?cat_id=1
```

**I want to be able to show the category name with Jquery like:**

```
$("#gift-label").html("<%= params[:cat_id].name %>");
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
# controller
@category = Category.find(params[:cat_id])

# category.js.erb file, which has to have the ending .erb
$("#gift-label").html("<%= @category.name %>");
```